# Simplify if (x) Some(y) else None?

Tags: scala

This common pattern feels a bit verbose:

```
if (condition) 
  Some(result)
else None
```

I was thinking of using a function to simplify:

```
def on[A](cond: Boolean)(f: => A) = if (cond) Some(f) else None
```

This reduces the top example to:

```
on (condition) { result }
```

Does something like this exist already?  Or is this overkill?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) includes the [option](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.1.1/scalaz_2.11-7.1.1-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.std.BooleanFunctions@option[A](cond:Boolean,a:=>A):Option[A]) function:

```
import scalaz.syntax.std.boolean._

true.option("foo") // Some("foo")
false.option("bar") // None
```

Comment: One of the things which concerned me about my function was that it didn't clearly signal that an option was being created.  This is both simple and overcomes that problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

You could create the `Option` first and filter on that with your condition:

```
Option(result).filter(condition)
```

or if `condition` is not related to `result`

```
Option(result).filter(_ => condition)
```

Comment: Interesting!  Though I'm a little concerned about (a) the unexpected (to me) order of condition/result, and (b) the tendency to always compute `result`, whether needed or not.  Hadn't thought of that, though!  Thanks!

Comment: compute result is a problem, guess you can fix it with
`Option(() => result).filter(_ => condition).map(_())`

Comment: i use this from time to time but it feels weird that one needs to evaluate result even if condition is false... I like scalaz approach where you can do `condition.option(result)` and that i believe is evaluated lazily, but this relies on implicits and scalaz is banned where i work anyways... i wish this was part of standard scala. Some sort of `Option.cond(condition, result)`

Answer (score 23):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, `Option` is now provided with the [`when`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#when[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) builder which does just that:

```
Option.when(condition)(result)
```

For instance:

```
Option.when(true)(45)
// Option[Int] = Some(45)
Option.when(false)(45)
// Option[Int] = None
```

Also note the coupled [`unless`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#unless[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) method which does the opposite.

Comment: Now that Scala 2.13 is out, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `PartialFunction` companion object and `condOpt`:

```
PartialFunction.condOpt(condition) {case true => result}
```

Usage:

```
 scala> PartialFunction.condOpt(false) {case true => 42}
 res0: Option[Int] = None

 scala> PartialFunction.condOpt(true) {case true => 42}
 res1: Option[Int] = Some(42)
```

Comment: Is that all 42 meant?  "True"?  Could have avoided building the earth... ;-)  Hadn't seen `condOpt` before, thanks!

Comment: It's definitely not the most useful scenario to use it but it may help in many other cases.

Comment: This is pretty neat! Definitely like this approach. Would have looked for it on `Option` companion object rather than `PartialFunction` but that doesn't really matter. 

Answer (score 2):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
val r = (1 == 2) ? Some(f) | None
System.out.println("Res = " + r)
```

Comment: Ah, the ever-handy ternary operator.  Thanks!  But I was hoping to avoid the repetitious addition of Some() and None.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that is quite straightforward:

```
Option(condition).collect{ case true => result }
```

A simple example:

```
scala> val enable = true
enable: Boolean = true

scala> Option(enable).collect{case true => "Yeah"}
res0: Option[String] = Some(Yeah)

scala> Option(!enable).collect{case true => "Yeah"}
res1: Option[String] = None
```

Here some advanced non-Boolean examples that put the condition into the pattern match:

```
val param = "beta"
Option(param).collect{case "alpha" => "first"} // gives None

Option(param).collect{case "alpha" => "first"
                      case "beta"  => "second"
                      case "gamma" => "third"} // gives Some(second)

val number = 999
Option(number).collect{case 0 => "zero"
                       case x if x > 10 => "too high"} // gives Some(too high)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Scalaz, the Typelevel cats ecosystem has the [mouse package](https://github.com/typelevel/mouse) with `option`:

```
scala> true.option("Its true!")
res0: Option[String] = Some(Its true!)
```